# Writing foreign letters in pygame screen

Tags: python, encoding, pygame

i had some pygame project that i needed to include non-English letters, specifically Amharic language letters. but the thing is even though my text editor reads and writes the letters pygame doesn't seem to understand them, it just puts them as a box.

here is a simple and similar example of the code i made:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
#            R    G    B
BLACK    = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = (255, 255, 255)
pygame.init()
fontObj = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 25)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
screen.fill(WHITE)
pygame.display.update()
while True:
    letterw= fontObj.render('በ', True, BLACK,WHITE)#this letter for example appeas as a box in the pygame screen
    #------------------------?---------------------
    letterwobj= letterw.get_rect()
    letterwobj.center = (20, 20)
    screen.blit(letterw,letterwobj)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I would be thank full for any suggestion and help.

Comment: You have to find and use fonts that contain these letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment suggested by  skrx at the top, i tried to download and use a font called 'nyala.ttf' but that didn't work so i tried to import the systems nyala font as follows `fontObj = pygame.font.SysFont('nyala', 25)` and it works.

Comment: Note that the users will also have to have this font installed on their computers. It would be better to store the font file in your game directory and load it with [`pygame.font.Font`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font).

Comment: ya, i tried to go to the system's font directory and get the 'nyala.ttf' file then copied it to the pygame library file where other fonts are stored, and loaded it with pygame.font.Font, but it was giving me an error saying it is unreadable i also tried to download the 'nyala.ttf' file from the web showed me the same error but when i load it from the system it worked.

Comment: Put it in the directory that contains your game .py file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the unicode operator:

```
u'በ'
```

or the unicode function:

```
unicode('በ')
```

but quite frankly it mostly depends on if pygame can render unicode characters.